# Linq db.tableUserDefinedVariable -- How To?

Tags: c#, database, linq, dynamic, drop-down-menu

What is the proper way to grab a databases table with a user defined variable? I figured it'd be pretty straightforward...

//I know in-line comments are bad, bear with me here..

string  sDDL1 = DropDownList1.SelectedValue; // sDDL1 = "tableX"

string  sDDL2 = DropDownList2.SelectedValue; // sDDL2 = "9000"

string  sDDL3 = DropDownList3.SelectedValue; // sDDL3 = "p.PK_XID"

//Hardcoded, everything works.

```
    dbDataContext  myDB =  new dbDataContext();


    var dynamicQuery = from p in myDB.tableX 
                       where p.PK_XID == 9000
                       select p;
```

//User defined data pukes at myDB.sDDL1. If I hardcode myDB.sDDL1, to myDB.tableX instead, the query will execute.

```
    dbDataContext  myDB =  new dbDataContext();


    var dynamicQuery = from p in myDB.sDDL1 //myDB.tableX instead, runs just fine...
                       where sDD3 == sDD2
                       select p;
```

Error:
'dbDataContext' does not contain a definition for 'sDDL1' and no extension method 'sDDL1' accepting a first argument of type 'dbDataContext' (are you missing a using directive or assembly reference?)

From what I understand, the error is telling me there is no such table "sDDL1" in the database, but, sDDL1 is a variable... shouldn't  myDB. be grabbing the variable's value?

Comment: You want to retrieve data from a table which is chosen based on user input? How are you populating your drop down lists?

Comment: <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Value="tableX">tableX</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="tableY">tableY</asp:ListItem>
 </asp:DropDownList>

Hardcoded to the test page. I have the values output to TextBoxes on the same page on Button_Click so I can see the DropDownList values are populating correctly; and they are.  If more details are needed let me know please!

Answer (score 0):

With that scenario, you'd need to reflect and do GetProperty to get the particular table, then cast it to the actual table type for the rest of the query to work fine.

You probably want to look at the DynamicQuery library or something similar.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx